# SQL Server How to pass a list of ids from sproc to function

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures, sql-function

Unlike most situations that I've found on the internet when people need to pass a list of id's to a sproc from an application like c# then split the id's up so they can be used in the WHERE clause like WHERE IN (4,5,6,7,7,8)

I need to call a sql function from a sql stored procedure passing a list of id's. and I need to know the best way to do this, if possible it would be nice not to introduce a .Split function.

I need to add a constraint to the function so that it will not build a result set of all the Horizontals .

--This is the shared sql function

```
ALTER FUNCTION [Storefront].[ufn_GetHorizontals] 
(
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT myColumList.* 'omitted'

FROM   Storefront.Horizontal h          with(nolock)                           JOIN
        Catelog.Part pt                 with(nolock)ON h.PartID = pt.ID        JOIN
        Catelog.Brand bd                with(nolock)ON pt.BrandID = bd.ID      JOIN
        Storefront.Size sz              with(nolock)ON sz.ID = h.SizeID        JOIN
        Storefront.Daylite dl           with(nolock)ON sz.ID = dl.SizeID       JOIN
        Storefront.Siteline sl          with(nolock)ON sl.ID = h.SitelineID    JOIN
        Storefront.Finish f             with(nolock)ON f.ID = h.FinishID      LEFT JOIN
        Storefront.HorizontalGlass hg   with(nolock)ON hg.HorizontalID = h.ID LEFT JOIN
        Catelog.Glass g                 with(nolock)ON hg.GlassID = g.ID
)
```

--Here is a few examples that show the way THAT I DO NOT WANT to approach this, because it is obviously wrong.

-Example 1
SELECT  *

FROM   Storefront.Leaf l         with(nolock)                    JOIN
        Storefront.LeafHorizontal lh     with(nolock)ON l.ID = lh.LeafID JOIN
        Storefront.ufn_GetHorizontals() h ON lh.HorizontalID = h.ID

WHERE l.ID = @LeafID;

- Example 2

  ALTER proc [Storefront].[proc_GetBayHorizontals]
   @BayID INT
  AS
  BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  ```
      SELECT  *

      FROM   Storefront.Bay b           with(nolock)           JOIN
              Storefront.BayHorizontal bh   with(nolock)ON b.ID = bh.BayID JOIN
              Storefront.ufn_GetHorizontals() h ON bh.HorizontalID = h.ID
  ```

  WHERE b.ID = @BayID;

---

I need something along the lines of this.

```
    ALTER FUNCTION [Storefront].[ufn_GetHorizontals] 
    (
      @MyListOfIdsFromTheStoredProcedure SOMEDATATYPE;
    )
    RETURNS TABLE 
    AS
    RETURN 
    (
        SELECT myColumList.* 'omitted'

    FROM   Storefront.Horizontal h          with(nolock)                           JOIN
            Catelog.Part pt                 with(nolock)ON h.PartID = pt.ID        JOIN
            Catelog.Brand bd                with(nolock)ON pt.BrandID = bd.ID      JOIN
            Storefront.Size sz              with(nolock)ON sz.ID = h.SizeID        JOIN
            Storefront.Daylite dl           with(nolock)ON sz.ID = dl.SizeID       JOIN
            Storefront.Siteline sl          with(nolock)ON sl.ID = h.SitelineID    JOIN
            Storefront.Finish f             with(nolock)ON f.ID = h.FinishID      LEFT JOIN
            Storefront.HorizontalGlass hg   with(nolock)ON hg.HorizontalID = h.ID LEFT JOIN
            Catelog.Glass g                 with(nolock)ON hg.GlassID = g.ID


  **********--->  WHERE h.ID IN(@MyListOfIdsFromTheStoredProcedure )

  )
```

*****-->Stored Procedure altered to a way like this.

```
    SELECT  *
              FROM
       Storefront.ufn_GetHorizontals(SELECT HorizontalID FROM Storefront.BayHorizontal bh
                                         WHERE bh.BayID = @BayID)
```

Thank you ahead of time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inline function `GetBayIDs()` takes a single integer and creates the XML document of IDs that is passed into your function and subsequently handed off to the `Split()` function to filter the dataset in your function.  It's hard to test without having `Storefront.BayHorizontal`, but I think this is pretty close...

```
create function dbo.GetBayIDs(@BayID int) returns xml
as
begin
  declare @xml varchar(max), @i int

  set @xml = '<root>'

  declare cr cursor local for
    SELECT HorizontalID
    FROM   Storefront.BayHorizontal bh
    WHERE  bh.BayID = @BayID

  open cr
  fetch next from cr into @i

  while @@fetch_status = 0
  begin
    set @xml = @xml + '<r>' + cast(@i as varchar(10)) + '</r>'
    fetch next from cr into @i
  end

  close cr
  deallocate cr

  set @xml = @xml + '</root>'

  return @xml
end
go

create function dbo.Split(@ids xml) returns @rtn table (id varchar(10))
as
begin
  insert into @rtn
  select r.value('.', 'varchar(10)') as [id]
  from @ids.nodes('//root/r') as records(r)

  return
end
go

ALTER FUNCTION [Storefront].[ufn_GetHorizontals] 
    (
      @idlist xml
    )
    RETURNS TABLE 
    AS
    RETURN 
    (
        SELECT myColumList.* 'omitted'
    FROM   Storefront.Horizontal h          with(nolock)                           JOIN
            Catelog.Part pt                 with(nolock)ON h.PartID = pt.ID        JOIN
            Catelog.Brand bd                with(nolock)ON pt.BrandID = bd.ID      JOIN
            Storefront.Size sz              with(nolock)ON sz.ID = h.SizeID        JOIN
            Storefront.Daylite dl           with(nolock)ON sz.ID = dl.SizeID       JOIN
            Storefront.Siteline sl          with(nolock)ON sl.ID = h.SitelineID    JOIN
            Storefront.Finish f             with(nolock)ON f.ID = h.FinishID      LEFT JOIN
            Storefront.HorizontalGlass hg   with(nolock)ON hg.HorizontalID = h.ID LEFT JOIN
            Catelog.Glass g                 with(nolock)ON hg.GlassID = g.ID      LEFT JOIN
            dbo.Split(@idlist) spl                      ON h.id = spl.id
  )
go

declare @BayID int = 123

SELECT *
FROM   Storefront.ufn_GetHorizontals(dbo.GetBayIDs(@BayID))

go
drop function dbo.Split
go
drop function dbo.GetIDs
```

Comment: I guess this means that I am going to have to utilize some type of string with XML of the split() approach?

Comment: I'm sure there are ways to do this without using XML, but this is certainly a simple approach.  I'll see if I can work this into an inline function...

Comment: If I could pass the id's to the function from the sproc like so would be awesome.   SELECT  *
              FROM
       Storefront.ufn_GetHorizontals(SELECT HorizontalID FROM Storefront.BayHorizontal bh
                                         WHERE bh.BayID = @BayID)

Comment: Aren't the ids already a comma separated list of values?  Are you also trying to build the list of integers with the GetHorizontals() function?

Comment: Isn't `@MyListOfIdsFromTheStoredProcedure` the comma separated list of ids?  Or, as it look closer at what you're trying to do, it seems that you want to pass in a single field dataset to the function that can be linked within the function to limit the rows returned by the function.  Correct?